# How to revalidate the form with jQuery after rules has been added/removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery with validation and unobtrusive validation plugins as part of the ASP.NET MVC 5 stack.

My form consists of so-called "form-groups" (a group of fields) and I have a checkbox which controls which form-group should be enabled/disabled.

I have two form-groups, both groups have its own required fields.

When I modify the checkbox checked state, I have to enable/disable the groups - and dynamically add/remove the required validation rules for each group.

Unfortunately the validation messages and the error classes doesn't get removed from the form.

I tried to remove it manually by revalidating the form/reseting the form - until now with no luck.

```
function enablePersonGroup() {
    app.enableFormGroup('.person-group');
    $('input[name=catalogValueId]').rules('add', { 
         required: true, 
         messages: { 
             required: requiredErrorMessage 
         } 
    });
}

function disablePersonGroup() {
    app.disableFormGroup('.person-group');

    // I CAN REMOVE THE RULES, BUT THE ERROR MESSAGE REMAINS:
    //$('input[name=catalogValueId]').rules('remove', 'required'); 
    delete $('form').validate().settings.rules['catalogValueId'];
}

 $(selector).change(function () {
     var type = $(selector+ ':checked').val();
     switch (type) {
         case 'Anonym':
             enableAnonymGroup();
             disablePersonGroup();
             break;
         case 'Person':
             disableAnonymGroup();
             enablePersonGroup();
             break;
     }
     $("form").validate().resetForm(); // DOESN'T HELP, ERROR MESSAGE REMAINS
});
```

Comment: There are a few options depending on the UI, but the real issue here is it does not address the server side validation. Instead use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` of similar attribute on your properties so that you get both server and client validation without any extra code.

Comment: "the real issue here is it does not address the server side validation" - Nope, server side validation works pretty fine, I'm using FluentValidation. Unfortunately FluentValidation doesn't automagically solve client-side validation for these conditional rules, that's why I have to reimplement these special rules on the client side as well.

Comment: Would have been useful to mention you were using FluentValidation :). One way of handling this is shown in [this article](http://eazolo.com/blog/fluentvalidation-client-side-custom-validation/)

Answer (score 2):

After dynamically updating the rules, if the form has any pending errors, you'll have to programmatically trigger a validation test using [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) either attached to the whole form, or attached to the individual field(s).  By doing this, any error messages will be updated or removed accordingly.

Trigger a validation test on entire form.  Similar to what happens when you click submit button.

```
$('#myform').valid();
```

Trigger a validation test on the input element.  Similar to what happens when you leave focus.

```
$('input[name="myinput"]').valid();
```

If you need to attach to a selector of multiple input elements, then you'll need a jQuery `.each()`.

```
$('.myInputs').each(function() {
    $(this).valid();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this, this is not working...Currently I'm trying to solve the problem with using "depends" (conditional validation rules) with no luck...

Comment: @Zsolt, this method works fine.   What does "not working" mean?

Comment: This method doesn't hide the "obsolete" field-validation-errors which are I guess filled by the unobtrusive validation plugin.

Comment: This has also another drawback, which is (ironically) that it triggers the validation on the form. 
Which means whenever you change the selection in the checkbox, new controls will be enabled, and the required fields for all these new controls would be "red" immediately since you've just triggered the validation for the whole form.
Of course I could trigger the validation only for the disabled controls to get rid of their disabled state. But I feel that this solution is too hacky.
What I would really need is to somehow reset the whole validation, as I would see the form after the first load.

Comment: @Zsolt, for resetting the form's validation, you should be using the `.resetForm()` method.  Why it's not working for you is a mystery as that's what it does.  Are there any JavaScript errors in the console?  http://jsfiddle.net/jjpxxz8t/

Comment: Thanks, but as I see in your sample you don't use the unobtrusive validation plugin which I'm using (in fact, it's used by ASP.NET MVC by default). I'm talking about this: https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive
Calling resetForm() doesn't clear the error messages in this case.
I will probably have to dig into the source and hack in the DOM manually, which I wanted to avoid... :-/

Comment: @Zsolt, AFAIK, the unobtrusive validation plugin merely provides a means for automatically initializing the jQuery Validate plugin via the data attributes created by ASP.  I don't believe it has any way of interfering with the default `.resetForm()` method.